# POST mulitple inputs in form with jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, post, input

I generate some inputs that looks something like this in HTML:

```
<input id='estemated_days' type='text' data-id='717' value='6'>

<select id='elements_grade' data-id='717'>
 <option value='1'></option>
 <option value='2'></option>
 <option value='3'></option>
</select>

<input id='estemated_days' type='text' data-id='718' value='4'>

<select id='elements_grade' data-id='718'>
 <option value='1'></option>
 <option value='2'></option>
 <option value='3'></option>
</select>
```

I generate about 10 at the time but showing you two as an example. How can I POST multiple input values to an external PHP file using jQuery? Previously I have used something like this (see code below) when submiting post data but this only seem to work for single fields with an ID - not a database generated `data-id`

```
//Initiate function when user clicks save
$("#save_courseplan").click(function() {

//Store the values of the fields as variables
var elements_grade = $('#elements_grade').val();
var estemated_days = $('#estemated_days').val();


$.post('../update.php', {

    estemated_days: estemated_days, //This for example will now represent 6
    elements_grade: elements_grade //And this 1

    }, function(data) {
    $('#updatestatus').html(data); //Display what update.php echoes out
 });
});
```

**EDIT**
 OK I don't think i was quite clear. I have dynamically created `input`fields. These fields has a `data-id` wich is fetched from a MySQL database.
 The database looks something like this:

```
+------------+------------+
| scpe_id    | scpe_days  |
+------------+------------+
| 717        | 6          |
+------------+------------+
| 718        | 4          |
+------------+------------+
```

Previously, I have been successful in updating single field based on the value it contains using the jQuery code i posted earlier in this thread. One ID contains a value, this value is beeing `$_POST` to my `update.php` file and then inserted in the database.

Now, however I cannot use ID, because I need to update mutiple rows at once, each with different database-ID. 
So what I would like is to first fetch the value of the `data-id`, to know what row to update, then fetch the value it holds to know what to be inserted - and then repeat for every `<input>`.

Comment: have you tried [serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method?

Comment: @undefined. It's not enough, he has to give all the elements a name attribute. as written in the docs you linked.

Comment: @gdoron you are right, of course.

Answer (score 3):

```
var queryString = $('form').serialize();
```

Done.

**Notes:**

- Make sure all the form elements, are inside the form element.
- All the form elements must have a `name` attribute .

[`serialize` docs](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Final code can be:

```
$.post('../update.php/?' + queryString, function(data) {
    $('#updatestatus').html(data);
});
```

Comment: Tell him also to put input and select inside form tag

Comment: Hello, thank's for your answer. Does `serialize` only works within a form? Because I'm not actually using `<form>` for my input fields, but I post the data based on the value of the ID as you can see in my jQuery code. Perhaps I should have mentioned this.

Comment: @David. It can work with any selector, It just take the elements in the selector and search for inputs inside. you can use this as well: `$('.common-class-for-all-inputs').serialize()`

Comment: @gdoron it seem to post multiple times now. Good, does serialize work on hidden inputs aswell? Because I would like to have the values of `data-id` posted also in order to know what rows to update in my database...

Comment: @David. I didn't understand your comment, and the question is changed every comment, can you please edit your question to a full question? notify me when you did. thanks.

Comment: @gdoron I updated my question a little. Please take a look and see if you understand now, thank you.

Comment: @David. I'm afraid it's even harder to understand it now.